# Is it possible to deep link to a specific revision of an Azure DevOps wiki page?

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, revision, azure-devops-wiki

I would like to generate a hyperlink to a read-only view of a specific revision of an Azure DevOps wiki page.  The links provided on the Revisions page navigate to a commit review page with compare and preview tabs and include a Revert button (when permitted).

I have tried

1. https://dev.azure.com/[organization]/[project]/_wiki/wikis/[project].wiki?pagePath=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fpage&version=[ETag] but the version is ignored and the latest revision is displayed.
2. https://dev.azure.com/[organization]/[project]/_wiki/wikis/[project].wiki?pagePath=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fpage&version=[commithash] but the version is ignored and the latest revision is displayed.
3. https://dev.azure.com/[organization]/[project]/_wiki/wikis/[project].wiki?_a=compare&wikiVersion=GBwikiMaster&pagePath=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fpage&version=[ETag]&view=preview which is viable but undesirable due to the risk of misguided reverts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only set read-only permissions on Wiki security, the page you get using the third form of link has no **Revert** button, so there should be no risk of misguided reverts.
[image: **enter image description here**]